# How to ignore one of multiple return values from require in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, require, eslint

I have a require statement like this

```
const {_Api, JsonRpc, _RpcError} = require('eosjs');
```

I am not using the underscored variables. But I am getting `no-unused-vars` warning for them. How can I ignore the values. I cannot replace simply leave them out because it requires a string literal before the comma unlike in a list. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC you don't need the unwanted items at all - since objects are used with keys (property names), you can only get the ones you want:

```
const { JsonRpc } = require('eosjs');
```